# Why aren't my images showing up in the README.md file on NuGet.org

Tags: github, nuget, nuget-package

I have published a NuGet package with a README.md file in it. The README is displayed normally but without images.

[How NuGet.org shows pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcOdD.png)

In F12 it looks like that:

[F12 Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GfoJ.png)

I am aware that NuGet.org only allows images from [trusted sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/package-readme-on-nuget-org). Therefore the images are stored on a [public GitHub repository](https://github.com/databinding-gmbh/ImageRepository).

I can see the images when editing them in VS code.

[Image Link in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaSbZ.png)

Also it is not an error while packing the nuspec.

Thanks for your help.

-Simon

Comment: Turns out that if you insert one not trusted link all the other ones are not trusted either. It worked now.